# Cargo Maven Tomcat NoInitialContextException When i already got Context

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, integration-testing, cargo-maven2-plugin

i am using cargo maven plugin to deploy my .war to a Tomcat 8 instance for integration testing.
The application is a jersey-based REST webinterface.
My problem appears in the underlying database connection pooling.
In integration test, there is a NoInitialContextException leading to a NullPointerexception.

I build 2 pools (1 for the application and one for oacc):

```
public class DBCPool {

   static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getRootLogger();
   static DataSource dbs = null;
   static DataSource oaccDS = null;

   private DBCPool() {};

public static boolean startup() {
      if (dbs != null && oaccDS != null) {
         LOGGER.trace("DBCPool startup when pool != null");
         return true;
      } else {
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Context ctxt = new InitialContext();
            LOGGER.debug("Initial context is: " + ctxt.getNameInNamespace());
            if (dbs == null) {
               LOGGER.trace("GTM DBCPool startup");
               dbs = (DataSource) ctxt.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/gtmdb");
               LOGGER.trace("Set dbs as " + dbs.toString());
            }
            if (oaccDS == null) {
               LOGGER.trace("OACC DBCPool startup");
               oaccDS = (DataSource) ctxt.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/oaccdb");
            }
            return true;
         } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.catching(e);
            return false;
         }
      }
   }

   public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      if (dbs == null) {
         LOGGER.debug("Had to start DBCPool in getConnection.");
      }
      return dbs.getConnection();
   }
```

There is some logging now which i added to understand the error, which will be deleted later.

The startup() is called on contextInitialized, therefore the DBCPool is set when the application is running.

As integration test, i've written:

```
 @Test
   public void getConnectionShouldReturnConnection() throws SQLException {
      DBCPool.startup();
      assertEquals(true, DBCPool.getConnection() != null);
   }
```

The DBCPool.startup() is unnecessary for the test, but helps here because it brings the underlying Exception to the log in cli.

I then use cargo maven plugin to deploy this to a tomcat 8 instance and failsafe to do the integration testing.
This is the pom.xml snippet:

```
<profile>
            <id>run-its</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>failsafe-it</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>failsafe-verify</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <container>
                                <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                            </container>
                            <configuration>
                                <home>${project.build.directory}/catalina-base</home>
                            </configuration>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-server</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-server</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The tomcat is started and the application is deployed.
Then even the DBCPool is set up and i get no NullPointerException when logging the toString() of the datasource. This is the startup log, the log4j part cut out because it got too long.

```
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.5.0:start (start-server) @ gtm ---
[INFO] [2.ContainerStartMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.5.0 for container tomcat8x
[INFO] You did not specify a container home nor any installer. CARGO will automatically download your container's binaries from [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/8.0.35/tomcat-8.0.35.zip].
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x starting...
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\gtm.war] to [C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target/catalina-base/webapps]...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
[...]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\gtm.war
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = oaccdb Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "50" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = oaccdb Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "5000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = gtmLog Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "30" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = gtmLog Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "5000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = gtmdb Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "50" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNUNG: Name = gtmdb Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "5000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:36 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,164 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\gtm\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,171 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Installed script engines
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,440 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_73, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,441 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 99 plugins
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,441 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,445 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG No scheduled items
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,445 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-07-17 10:07:37,447 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
[...]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.558 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO   - GTM servlet context initialized
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG  - Initial context is: java:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - GTM DBCPool startup
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - Set dbs as org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@79270e48
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - OACC DBCPool startup
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:37 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   de.osg.gtm.web
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:37 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Root resource classes found:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   class de.osg.gtm.web.FrontendService
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:37 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: No provider classes found.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:37 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\gtm.war has finished in 2,448 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\host-manager
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\host-manager has finished in 31 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\manager
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\catalina-base\webapps\manager has finished in 24 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 17, 2016 10:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFORMATION: Server startup in 2821 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x started on port [8080]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (failsafe-it) @ gtm ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\Users\timki\git\gtm-code\gtm\target\failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
```

As you can see from

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.558 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO   - GTM servlet context initialized
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG  - Initial context is: java:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - GTM DBCPool startup
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - Set dbs as org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@79270e48
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 10:07:37.565 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE  - OACC DBCPool startup
```

I got the initialContext and even the datasource from the lookup.
But then, in testing:

```
10:07:39.631 [main] ERROR  - Catching
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameInNamespace(InitialContext.java:563) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at de.osg.gtm.management.DBCPool.startup(DBCPool.java:34) [classes/:?]
    at de.osg.gtm.management.DBCPoolIT.getConnectionShouldReturnConnection(DBCPoolIT.java:13) [test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161) [surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121) [surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
10:07:39.637 [main] DEBUG  - Had to start DBCPool in getConnection.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.684 sec <<< FAILURE! - in de.osg.gtm.management.DBCPoolIT
getConnectionShouldReturnConnection(de.osg.gtm.management.DBCPoolIT)  Time elapsed: 0.656 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.osg.gtm.management.DBCPoolIT.getConnectionShouldReturnConnection(DBCPoolIT.java:14)
```

So there it is. I get the DBCPool set up, but then in testing the dbs (databasesource, the DBCPool instance) is null again and initialContext can not be retrieved.

I guess i did something wrong in configuring failsafe, so that it does not test the deployed application and therefore does not get a Context. But i do not find my error, no matter how many examples and tutorials i study.
I had the same error with maven tomcat plugin and hoped to solve it with the cargo maven plugin, but no.

Thanks in advance for any help.
RMG

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about the maven lifecycle and when the cargo-maven2-plugin starts to work? Maybe the application will be deployed after the integration tests.

If the lifecycle would be like:

```
Maven: clean > test > it-test > install > deploy
```

Your `it-suite` would run without the necessary tomcat container. And fail with good reasons.

Maybe you split your profile `run-its` into:

1. deploy application with cargo (exclude its)
2. run its (exclude deployment)

This approach would ensure the up-and-running tomcat container.